# IP masquerading?

Tags: routing

I have a device that does not support a routed network - it does not have an entry for a gateway and has a fixed IP address that can not be changed. I'd like to connect it to a network using some sort of router.

The device's fixed IP address is 192.168.120.1.
I have a laptop at 192.168.1.100 that needs to communicate with the device at 192.168.120.1.

I'm thinking that it should be possible to setup a router to do some sort of translation / masquerading to connect make the connection. I have a spare Sonicwall NSA 240 that should do the job but I'm not sure of the settings. Traffic from the laptop would need to "appear" to come from an IP address on the 192.168.120.x subnet.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a job for NAT!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an additional IP on your Laptop in the subnet 192.168.120.x, if the laptop and the static device can be connected in the same broadcast network.

Otherwise, NAT is the way

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem is you can't configure gateway on one of your devices, you will have to use NATing as well as port forwarding rules in your router.

Configure it like this.

Router::

Interface 1 : IP :: 192.168.120.x

Interface 2 : IP :: 192.168 1.x

Laptop::

IP :: 192.168.1.100 ; gateway :: 192.168.1.x

Add a **NAT rule at interface 1**. Now if the connection is generated from laptop then NATing will translate the traffic for 192.168.120.1 with 192.168.120.x , i.e., the IP of the router.
This will work for traffic initiated from your laptop.

But when initiated from other device, it will have to send traffic explicitly to 192.168.120.x to be able to communicate with laptop since no default gateway is configured on this device.
To make it work you will have to **add port forwarding rules** on your router so as to forward all traffic coming to interface 1 from 192.168.120.1 to 192.168.1.100.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this with Sonicwall or perhaps dd-wrt?

Comment: I haven't worked with it but you can configure the SonicWALL just as other router via GUI. For NAT you can add directly while configuring the interface of SonicWALL. For port forwarding there will be a separate settings tab for it.

Comment: I was able to setup 1:1 NAT in the Sonicwall. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your two devices are on the same physical network or vlan you can give your computer nic two ip addresses.

In windows give your nic a static address. Click advanced at the bottom of the Nics  properties page. From there you can add a second address that can communicate with 192.168.120.1 device like 192.168.120.2.

Layer 2 networks don't really "care" about the ip addresses but the devices do. That's why this is possible.

I use this method all the time when setting up devices.

If you don't want to do that nat or regular routing are your options.

If you are simply trying to communicate and use Dd-wrt this is the basic idea. Keep in mind this is a home/small business router normally. Set your "internet port" or "Wan port" (this is the terminology used on most home routes, it's just a routed interface) as 192.168.120.2. Plug in your device. Make the lan side (which is like giving the vlan the switch ports are using an ip address or in Cisco is called an svi) 192.168.1.2, plug in your laptop. Dd-wrt will allow the two networks to route.

If you must connect to a 192.168.1.### address then add the nat and port forwarding. There are tabs for port forwarding and the tab for nat is called nat/QoS I  Dd-wrt. [Link to a tutorial here](https://www.flashrouters.com/blog/2012/09/14/how-to-use-port-forwarding-with-dd-wrt-routers-dd-wrt-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need help setting up NAT, I think this document will help you.
You want to set up One-to-One NAT.

https://www.sonicwall.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/170505782921100